# How do i input a more than 1 digit number?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dosbox

I want to check if they are equal, unequal, greater or lesser

```
Dosseg
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
MsgEq db 'Numbers are Equal $'
MsgUneq db 'Numbers are Unequal and $'
MsgGr db ' First Number is greater than second number $'
MsgLs db ' First Number is lesser than second number $'
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 1     ; input first number
int 21h
mov bl, al     ; saving first number to bl from al

mov al, 1      ; input second number
int 21h
mov cl, al    ; saving second number to cl from al

L1:            
cmp bl,cl       ; Comparing whether they are equal or not
je EQUAL     ; Jump to Equal box, where we print the equal msg

mov dl, 10     ; for next line feed
mov ah, 2
int 21h
mov dl, 13      ; for carriage return
mov ah, 2
int 21h

mov dx, offset MsgUneq   ; but if not equal, then print msg they are not equal
mov ah, 9
int 21h

cmp bl, cl          ; again compare to check the first is greater or lesser
jge Greater         ; if greater, jump to greater to print a greater msg

mov dx, offset MsgLs  ; but if not greater, print lesser msg
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp PRINT



Greater:
mov dx, offset MsgGr
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp PRINT


EQUAL:
mov dl, 10     ; for next line feed
mov ah, 2
int 21h
mov dl, 13      ; for carriage return
mov ah, 2
int 21h

mov dx, offset MsgEq
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp PRINT



PRINT:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp

end main
```

Comment: Reserve a variable for each of two numbers (`First DB 0 ; Second DB 0`). Input the first digit of the first number, and while it's not Enter (`CMP AL,0Dh`). convert it from **char** to **binary** (`SUB AL,'0'`),  temporary save somewhere (`MOV BL,AL`). multiply the reserved variable by 10 and add the binary digit to the variable (`ADD [First],BL`).. Repeat and then prompt for the second number.

Comment: I tried this but it s not good. Can you tell me how to do that?                                                            first db 0
second db 0
.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

mov ah, 1     ; input first number
int 21h
cmp al, 0d
sub al, '0'
mov bl, al     ; saving first number to bl from al
add [first], bl

mov al, 1      ; input second number
int 21h
cmp al, 0d
sub al, '0'
mov cl, al    ; saving second number to cl from al
add [second], bl

Answer (score 0):

```
Dosseg
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
First  DB 0  ; Variable for the binary number 0..255.
Second DB 0  ; Variable for the binary number 0..255.
MsgPrompt db 'Enter two numbers between 0 and 255:',13,10,'$'
MsgEq db 'Numbers are Equal.',13,10,'$'
MsgUneq db 'Numbers are Unequal and $'
MsgGr db ' First Number is greater than second number.',13,10,'$'
MsgLs db ' First Number is lesser than second number.',13,10,'$'

.code
main proc
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax

MOV DX, offset MsgPrompt
MOV AH,9
INT 21h   ; Display the prompt.         

InputFirst:
mov ah, 1     ; input first number
int 21h
CMP AL,0Dh    ; End of input?
JE InputSecond
SUB AL,'0'     ; Convert decimal digit to binary number.
mov bl, al     ; saving first number to bl from al
MOV DL,10
MOV AL,[First]
MUL DL
ADD AL,BL
MOV [First],AL
JMP InputFirst

InputSecond:
; That was WRONG! mov al, 1      ; input second number
MOV AH, 1      ; input second number
int 21h
CMP AL,0Dh  ; End of input?
JE Compare
SUB AL,'0'     ; Convert decimal digit to binary number.
mov cl, al    ; saving second number to cl from al
MOV DL,10
MOV AL,[Second]
MUL DL
ADD AL,CL
MOV [Second],AL
JMP InputSecond

Compare:
MOV BL,[First]
MOV CL,[Second]
cmp bl,cl       ; Comparing whether they are equal or not
je EQUAL     ; Jump to Equal box, where we print the equal msg

mov dx, offset MsgUneq   ; but if not equal, then print msg they are not equal
mov ah, 9
int 21h

cmp bl, cl          ; again compare to check the first is greater or lesser
jge Greater         ; if greater, jump to greater to print a greater msg

mov dx, offset MsgLs  ; but if not greater, print lesser msg
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp PRINT

Greater:
mov dx, offset MsgGr
mov ah, 9
int 21h
jmp PRINT

EQUAL:
mov dx, offset MsgEq
mov ah, 9
int 21h
; jmp PRINT 

PRINT:      ; Better call this label Exit:
mov ah,4ch
int 21h
main endp

end main
```